# When using realm where does business logic sit

Tags: realm

We currently designing a mobile app and the client has requested we have the ability to work offline and sync data when online again. I'm looking at using realm as it seems to make having an offline state really easy, however I'm a bit confused about where any server side logic would live. Am I right in that realm isn't really designed to have server side logic? You are just persisting data to the cloud when the cloud is available but you aren't actually in charge of building an API with and logic behind it?

Edit.

Reading further maybe Azure offline data sync is a better option because you can write the server side code? Am I correct in this decision that if I want server side code I can't use realm?

Thansk Michael

Answer (score 0):

Realm Mobile Platform is designed for offline data access since it uses the full power of Realm Mobile Database as the client data store. However, that doesn't mean you are limited to only client-side interactions. We offer a Node.js SDK in the Professional and Enterprise editions where you can work with the same copy of Realm data from the mobile clients in a Linux environment.

The Node.js SDK offers the ability to open any Realm, [query or perform write transactions on the server](https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/pe-ee/#data-access) which will push data out to the client(s). In addition, it has [event-handling capabilities](https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/pe-ee/#event-handling), where you can register callbacks to perform logic in response to data changes performed on client devices.

To make it easier to get started with the event-handling functionality, we launched [Realm Functions](https://news.realm.io/news/serverless-logic-with-realm-introducing-realm-functions/) which allows you to create Javascript functions through the Realm Object Server dashboard, which will then run in response to data changes. Underneath the hood this uses the Node.js SDK to power it.

The sum total of all of this is that you should be able to build any server-side business logic that you need. By using Realm's sync as the transport layer, your mobile development can focus on the application logic versus networking and data transformation. Likewise, your server has an exact copy of the data to perform logic as well. Both sides operate independently, so offline changes will always sync back up!